# .Net strange behavior with Convert.ToDecimal and culture

Tags: c#, .net

Today I had a strange problem on my job, I spent seven hours on a solution but I haven't been successful alone. I have four production machines, two with errors and two without. The error does not happen on my development machine. In the code below:

```
//value = "120,01"
object objectValue = value;                  

objectValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"));

string description = string.Format("d {0} - N {1}:", value, (Convert.ToDecimal(objectValue , new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR")).ToString(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR"))));

//Production two results:

//Machine 01: d 120,01 - N 120,01:
//Machine 02: d 120,01 - N 12001:
```

Even with the culture set, the problem occurs. After shutting the IIS Process down on the four machines, they work OK now.

But what happened?

Comment: The machine's default culture setting is cached at the start of a program.  You'd have to call CultureInfo.ClearCachedData() to reset it.  Not practical of course, you'd just recycle the application pool.  Why your code changes had no effect is harder to guess. Practice recycling the application pool.  Best to tag questions about asp.net apps with [asp.net]

Comment: If you want to set the culture for the entire application you can set it in the thread: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the decimal separator became `.`.

The `CultureInfo` constructor you use resolves to [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h898a16(v=vs.110).aspx), with the `useUserOverride`parameter at `true`. See how this parameter is used in the Remarks.

Is it possible that the language settings for the user running the Application Pool had been changed ?